# how to make statement in type mediatR Unit when I delete item

Tags: c#, if-statement, asp.net-web-api, mediatr

In my **ItemController.cs** I make delete action, I want to catch false value in statement result when the Id is not exsist in database. How to get false in type Unit in mediatR ?

```
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        var response = new RowResponse<ItemDto>();
        var result = await _mediator.Send(new ItemDeleteHandler.Command { Id = id });

        if (result == null)
        {
            response.IsOk = false;
            response.ErrorMessage = "Data not found";
        }
        else
        {
            response.IsOk = true;
            response.ErrorMessage = "item with id " + id + " was deleted";
        }
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

on code **if (result == null)**

I have an error say

```
The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'Unit' is never equal to null of type 'Unit?'
```

so I can not make statement in my **ItemController.cs** the value is {()}

and in my  **ItemDeleteHandler.cs**

```
public class ItemDeleteHandler
{
    public class Command : IRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        public Validator()
        {
            RuleFor(c => c.Id).GreaterThan(0);
        }
    }


    public class CommandHandler : IRequestHandler<Command, Unit>
    {
        private readonly FinContext _db;
        public CommandHandler(FinContext db) => _db = db;
        public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var response = new RowResponse<ItemDto>();

            var itemData = await _db.Item.FindAsync(req.Id);
            if (itemData == null)
            {
                response.IsOk = false;
                response.ErrorMessage = "Data not found";
                return Unit.Value;
            }
            else 
            {
                response.IsOk = true;
                response.ErrorMessage = "Item with id " + req.Id + " has been deleted" ;
            }
            
            _db.Item.Remove(itemData);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            return Unit.Value;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Unit for returns.
Try returning Response object.